# how to sum an equatioin for a list of fields in excel

Tags: excel

My equation looks like this

```
J2

=IF(AND(B2=D2,B2=1),1,0)
```

so clearly the cell under will be

```
J3 
=IF(AND(B3=D3,B3=1),1,0)
```

and so on

at the end of these cells, I have an equation to get the sum of all calculated values above

```
=SUM(J2:J101)
```

is there a way to build this equation without the need of making 100 cells before the sum

i mean can I do something like this?

```
=SUM(IF(AND(B2:B101=D2:D101,B2:B101=1),1,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly then you should just be able to use a `COUNTIFS` ...

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B101,1,D2:D101,1)
```

... if `B` has to be 1 then so does `D` and because you're returning **1** if true then a COUNTIFS yields the same result as a SUM in this scenario.